# No connection with Magento 1 SOAP API via https (SSL)

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2, ssl, https, wsdl

I try to get customer datas via a PHP script and the **Magento 1 SOAP API**. At my development system, every thing is works well.

But now when I try to use it at the online Shop with **active SSL**, I get no connections to the **wsdl object**.

My PHP call

```
$wsdl = 'https://urltoshop/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1';
$user = 'soapuser';
$pass = 'paasword';
...
//options for ssl in php 5.6.5
$opts = array(
    'ssl' => array(
            'ciphers' => 'SHA-256',
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false
    )
);
// SOAP 1.2 client
$params = array(
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'verifypeer' => false,
    'verifyhost' => false,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'trace' => 1,
    'exceptions' => 1,
    'connection_timeout' => 180,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts)
);
$proxy = new SoapClient($wsdl);
... 
try {
   $sessionId = $proxy->login($user, $pass);
} catch (Exception $e) {
   $sessionId = null;
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**And I get always the error message like this:**

> SoapFault: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://urltoshop/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity

This url works in a webbrowser, and I get the xml structure. I have already try a lot of SoapClient options like:

```
'verifyhost' => false, 
'verify_peer' => false, '
'verify_peer_name' => false 
 'ssl' => array('allow_self_signed' => true));
```

etc...

But nothing works for me.

Is this a problem with my PHP script, or a config problem in my Apache Webserver? Or something in the Magento configuration?

Has any of you guys any experience with such a constellation like this?

Does everyone know a good manual page, how to setup the SOAP API in Magento incl. a https:// connection?

Answer (score 2):

I´ve found the problem with the connection failure. For those who running in the same problems:

In my case there was missing the intermediate certificate in the webserver. This was not a problem for the web Browser, but for the SOAP client.

When I checked the installed certificate with (https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html), I got a result like this:
[image]

After I had insert the intermediate certificate content, everything was working well.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to define the properties is

```
$paramsSoap = array(
                        "trace" => 1,
                        "location" => "<your-url>",
                        'exceptions' => 1,
                        "stream_context" => stream_context_create(
                            array(
                                'ssl' => array(
                                    'verify_peer'       => false,
                                    'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    );
    
    $client = new SoapClient("<your-url>?wsdl",$paramsSoap);
```